# Laravel @foreach Repeating Same Data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

when I am trying to add @foreach 3 times it's repeating my data. how do I solve this?
and am using Livewire.

Small Summery :
I will try to make a Student Management system using Laravel and livewire. basically, I am trying to make a payment system based on Monthly, Termly, and Year so it's also separate to more. Example We have Different price Value of Monthly Payment Scheme Students.

this is my code

```
 public function mount($students){
        $students = Student::With('FeeScheem','FeeScheemInd','FeeGroup','FeeMaster','FeeCollector')
        ->where('students.stu_id',$students )
        ->get();
        $this->students = $students;
     
        // DD($students);
    }
```

Eloquent Relationship

```
public function FeeScheem()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(FeeScheem::class, 'fs_id', 'stu_fee_scheems');
               
    }
    public function FeeScheemInd()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(FeeScheemInd::class, 'ind_id', 'stu_ind_fee_scheems');
        
    }

    public function FeeGroup()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(FeeGroup::class, 'fee_group_fee_scheem_id', 'stu_fee_scheems');
    }

    public function FeeMaster()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(FeeMaster::class, 'fee_master_ind_fs_id', 'stu_ind_fee_scheems'); 
    }

    public function FeeCollector()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SchoolFeeCollector::class, 'fc_stu_id', 'stu_id');
    }
```

This is My Blade File

```
<tbody>
  
  @foreach($students as $Student)
  
  @foreach($Student->FeeGroup as $FeeG)
  
  @foreach($Student->FeeCollector as $FeeC)
  
  
  
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>{{$FeeG->fee_group_name}}</td>
      <td>{{$FeeG->fee_master_due_date}}</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>{{$Student->FeeMaster->fee_master_amount}}</td>
    </tr>
   
@endforeach
@endforeach
@endforeach
  </tbody>
```

[Here the table view in Blade file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnmaP.png)

Comment: I think remove your `-` that inside `@else` clause will solve your question

Comment: @edisonthk It Not the i Change it